# How to hash image source url in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url, hash

Hi i want to send url with hash of image source.How can do it ?

Code :

```
Image img_ = new Image();          
img_.ImageUrl = "ShowImageInRuntime.aspx?FileName=C://Images//Image.jpg";
```

i dont want to see my local path in page.Thx for your help

Comment: You'll need to store the local path somewhere. Do you have storage for your application that you can store paths in and look them up, e.g. a database? If there's a small fixed set you could hard-code the paths into your app if necessary. Otherwise you'll have to serve encrypted paths and decrypt them in ShowImageAtRuntime (then validate before using!) although there's a danger a user might be able to construct their own encrypted paths.

Comment: As long as the secret used for encryption remains safe user may not be able to create a valid encrypted string by randomly changing characters and making an educated guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need either perform encryption of the path and base 64 encode before sending and do the reverse in the handler.

Other option is to maintain a mapping XML where the XML would contain the path and corresponding identifier. In your application get the node with the path and pick the id and send append it to url. In the handler do the reverse to fetch the path.

**UPDATE** : Adding Sample code

XML file with GUID as ID and corresponding fileName. by using guid, people cannot guess the random ids easily.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mappings>
  <map id="485D9075B9CA4d8d9DBA1AD9CD09FC13" fileName="c:\images\image1.jpg"/>
  <map id="475D4A22B1FA4eda8234007BD327D7B9" fileName="c:\images\image2.jpg"/>
  <map id="77623BF3094440c49AC65CEF76D1B824" fileName="c:\images\image3.jpg"/>
</mappings>
```

Using LINQ to XML

```
public class ImageMapper
{
    private XDocument Document { get; set; }

    public ImageMapManager()
    {
        Document = XDocument.Load("Map.xml");
    }

    public string GetFileNameFromId(string id)
    {
        var result = from node in Document.Descendants("map")
                     where node.Attribute("id").Value.Equals(id, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                     select node.Attribute("fileName").Value;
        return (result == null || result.Count() == 0) ? null : result.ElementAt(0);
    }
    public string GetIdFromFileName(string fileName)
    {
        var result = from node in Document.Descendants("map")
                     where node.Attribute("fileName").Value.Equals(fileName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                     select node.Attribute("id").Value;
        return (result == null || result.Count() == 0) ? null : result.ElementAt(0);

    }
}
```